# How do I get a UserControl or View to refresh, redraw, repaint, etc.?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a situation whereby codebehind in a UserControl populates a Grid object with child Grids containing 1 ColumnDefinition and N Row Definitions.  Each row definition contains various user controls.

When the code is done creating the control layout, something is being left over in that controls that have been removed are still appearing on top of the controls that should be there.

I think all I need to do is somehow force a repaint of the screen but how is that done?

I've tried UpdateLayout, InvalidateArrange, InvalidateMeasure, etc etc, nothing will force the layout to refresh.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the controls are removed correctly? My bet is they are not, but hard to say without any code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any call anything to trigger a re-draw, only to trigger re-layouting and that usually only if you write your own panels.

If you see something, it's in the visual tree.